# NSObjectInaccessibleException - Deleting all entity objects - NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a function responsible for deleting all the items of an entity:

```
func removeItems() {
    if let managedContext = managedObjectContext {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Ent", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        fetchRequest.entity = entity
        fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = false

        var error: NSError?
        var results = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)

        for result in results as [NSManagedObject] {
            managedContext.deleteObject(result)
        }

        if !managedContext.save(&error) {
            println("could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

My application consists of a TabBar with 3 screens:

The first tab presents a list of cities, and when one is selected, a segue is executed and goes to a product listing page, in which the user can "tag" products.

The second tab has a screen that shows the listing of these branded products, and also has a badge showing the amount of products

However, I need to delete all objects of this entity whenever the user selects a different city or when he starts the application after terminated.

For the first case, I delete all the objects in "prepareForSegue" function when the user selects a city, and it works perfectly.

The problem comes when I try to run the second case. 
If I try to call the remove function in the "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" of the AppDelegate or "viewDidLoad" in the first tab, the bank is corrupted, and I get the following message when I try to enter in the second tab:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0xd000000000140000 ''**

But if I remove the function of "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" or "viewDidLoad" the first tab, the application works perfectly.

Looking more closely, the error is occurring in the second tab (the product listing).

I have a variable in which I use to keep up the items in the table (in the second tab):

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Entidade", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nome", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1]

    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: managedContext,
        sectionNameKeyPath: "nome",
        cacheName: "Entidade")

    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

And the error is occurring exactly this line of the second tab:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()

    var error: NSError?
    if !fetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error) { // <----- HERE
       fatalCoreDataError(error)
    }
}
```

Would anyone have any suggestions of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was entirely in the second tab.

The answer to the problem was to remove the variable:

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    .
    .
    .
}()
```

Now the "viewDidLoad" the second tab was as follows (the fetch was removed):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()
}
```

Was added the following variable:

```
var entities = [Entidade]()
```

And added the following methods:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    fetchLog()
}
```

And

```
func fetchLog() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entidade")

    var error: NSError? = nil

    if let results = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as? [Entidade] {
        self.entities = results
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

With these changes, I can finally remove the objects when the application is started by placing the following code in the cities list screen:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    appDelegate.removeItens()
}
```

Or choose to call the "removeItems()" method in AppDelegate when the application starts or ends.

If anyone needs, I can post the entire source code of the screens.

**Updated**

I found out what really happened, I have a method in AppDelegate in which is responsible for updating the "badgeValue" tab of the list whenever a user marks a product.

He was as follows (and was called every time a change occurred in managedObjectContext):

```
func updateUI() {
    let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as UITabBarController

    if let tabBarViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers {
        let navigationController = tabBarViewControllers[3] as UINavigationController
        let listViewController = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as ListViewController
        listViewController.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext // <--- Here's the problem

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entidade")
        if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) {
            navigationController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = String(fetchResults.count)
        }
    }
}
```

I can not set the managedObjectContext to a screen this way, I need to assign it only once in the "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions", so I got to keep the old code to take advantage of NSFetchedResultsController